# Why does linux recognise a C# .cs file as a C++ source file?

Tags: c++, file-command, c#

I used the file command on a c# source file, and linux thought it was a c++ file. What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the man page for the `file` command:

> $ man file
>
> ...
>
> file tests each argument in an attempt to classify it.
>   There are three sets of tests, performed in this order: ***filesystem
>   tests***, ***magic tests***, and ***language tests***. The first test that succeeds
>   causes the file type to be printed.

It's the third test (*language tests*) that `file` performs that's categorizing this file as a C++ file.

> Once file has determined the character set used in a text-type file,
>   it will attempt to determine in what language the file is written. 
>   The language tests look for particular strings (cf.  #include
>   ) that can appear anywhere in the first few blocks of a file.  For example, the keyword .br indicates that the file is most likely a
>   troff(1) input file, just as the keyword struct indicates a C program.
>   These tests are less reliable than the previous two groups, so they are performed last. The language test routines also test for some
>   miscellany (such as tar(1) archives).

C# files most closely match to C++ files and so `file` "guesses" that the .cs file is a C++ file.

#### Example

```
$ more blah.cs
// A Hello World! program in C#.
using System;
namespace HelloWorld
{
    class Hello
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

            // Keep the console window open in debug mode.
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Checking with `file`:

```
$ file blah.cs
blah.cs: ASCII C++ program text
```

Comment: Add to this: the original file command looks only at file contents, not the filename. So it doesn’t recognize that a .cs file contains syntax that looks vaguely like C++ but which is actually a different language C#. // Many folks extend file to look at the filename as well, but that produces other problems.